# How to add TextChanged event to the label in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been working on a mobile chat application and displaying the messages in the inbox of a user using a label. I need to detect URLs, tags and some special kind of text. text may change at any time. I need to implement the **TextChanged** event for the **Label**. So that I can perform my operations to detect URLs, tags, etc.

[image: sample picture]

All the text in the above image will be displayed using a single label. Whenever the text is changed, the label should detect the **TextChanged** event and update the colors and decorations of the detected URLs and tags using spans.

We did this in **WPF** using **TextBlock** control. Now we have to implement it in our mobile application.

Is there any way to implement the TextChanged event for the Label in **Xamarin.Forms**.

Comment: You already asked this question.  Please do not post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you have to implement label that is capable of converting html tags to formatted text or whatever method you are using. Then you should bind your text to method that collects data from probably remote source. Text changed event handler is used rather to detect user input in XF. I don't know how your application works but, using MVVM models and bindings will save you a lot of frustrations when working with Xamarin UI.

Answer (score 0):

Label.OnTextChanged(EventArgs) Method will be there, you can use this.

```
 Entry1 _TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(.... put some condition here....)
    {
        entryField.Text = e.OldTextValue;
    }
}
```

Reference link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Entry.TextChanged?view=xamarin-forms